# xcode12 ViewController.swift window not full displayer

Tags: swift, xcode12

I've tried to refactor > rename an IBOutlet in xcode version 12.4 (12D4e), but the popup window seem to be not full displayed([like this attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAMCP.png)). This thing made in quite not easy to see.
How to make the window full display like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lr50U.png), can anybody help me please, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it to Full Screen from a storyboard like this:
[image: You can change it to Full Screen from storyboard like this:]

or by programming:

```
    self.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
```

[image]

Comment: This is not at all what OP asked.

Comment: Thank you @Bar Kozlovski, even I'm so new with Xcode. Could you give me which menu I can open window follow the picture you attached please.

Comment: I was tried with @Bar Kozlovski but refactor > rename window still the same, issue not solved. Is it related with my view window configured? [picture](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cEEchwdqa-YYQeU6FlLI2mp4WNoG_GJf/view?usp=sharing)